# How to properly make a train/test split using `torchdata`?

Tags: pytorch, torchdata

I've been using the `torchdata` library (v0.6.0) to construct datapipes for my machine learning model, but I can't seem to figure out how `torchdata` expects its users to make a train/test split.

Supposing I have a datapipe `dp`, my first attempt was to use the `Sampler` datapipe along with a `torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler` (which is what I expected from [this part of the documentation](https://pytorch.org/data/beta/generated/torchdata.datapipes.iter.Sampler.html#torchdata.datapipes.iter.Sampler)), but this doesn't work how I would've thought:

```py
>>> dp = SequenceWrapper(range(5))
>>> Sampler(dp,SubsetRandomSampler([0, 1, 2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: 'SubsetRandomSampler' object is not callable
```

Maybe torchdata has it's own samplers I'm not familiar with.

The only other way I can think of doing this would be to use a `Demultiplexer`, but this feels unclean to me, because we have to enumerate then "de-enumerate":

```py
>>> train_len = len(dp) * 0.8
>>> dp1, dp2 = dp.enumerate().demux(num_instances=2, classifier_fn=lambda x: x[0] >= train_len)
>>> dp1, dp2 = (d.map(lambda x: x[1]) for d in (dp1, dp2))
```

Is there an "intended" way of doing this with `torchdata` which I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyTorch's tutorial on using DataPipes answers the question](https://pytorch.org/data/main/dp_tutorial.html):

```py
import torchdata.datapipes.iter as pipes
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split

# initialize DataPipe with dummy values
dp = pipes.IterableWrapper(range(5))

# create train/test split ratio sizes (assuming 80/20 split)
train_size, test_test = int(len(dp) * 0.8), len(dp) - (int(len(dp) * 0.8))

# split dataset into train/test sets
train_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dp, [train_size, test_size])

# create batch sizes for train and test dataloaders
# (loading everything into memory, no minibatches)
batch_train, batch_test = len(train_dataset), len(test_dataset)

# create train and test dataloaders
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_train, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_test)

# train model
for i, j in train_dataloader:
    ...
    preds = model(i)
    loss = loss_fn(preds, j)
    ....
```

If you want to use the built-in `random_split()` method of Iterable-style DataPipe:

```py
train_dataset, test_dataset = dp.random_split(total_length=len(dp), weights={"train": 0.8, "test": 0.2}, seed=42)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_train, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_test)
```

**Edit**: You can directly access the `DataPipe` from within the split dataset (this works with both `IterDataPipe` and `MapDataPipe`:

```py
train_dp = train_dataset.dataset
test_dp = test_dataset.dataset
```

If you want the output of the `random_split()` function to be a `MapDataPipe`, you can always wrap the outputs in `SequenceWrapper()`:

```py
from torchdata.datapipes.map import SequenceWrapper

train_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dp, [train_size, test_size])
train_mdp = SequenceWrapper(train_dataset)
test_mdp = SequenceWrapper(test_dataset)
```

And same idea with `IterDataPipe`:

```py
train_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dp, [train_size, test_size])
train_idp = pipes.IterableWrapper(train_dataset)
test_idp = pipes.IterableWrapper(test_dataset)
```

Comment: sorry to deselect your answer, but I just realized the `random_split` method only exists for `IterDataPipe`s, not `MapDataPipe`s, the latter of which I work with more often.

Comment: It's the exact same solution. Did you not try to use the answer? I've tried it with `Iterative DataPipe` and with `Map DataPipe`. If you meant to ask another question, then make another question, but my solution (which is based on the official PyTorch solution, using the minimal reproducible example that /you/ provided) answers your question. Respectively, run that answer as accepted.

Comment: ah I see, so the first solution does indeed work even for MapDataPipes, whereas they lack a `random_split` method themselves. I was just hoping that the result of the random_split would again be two datapipes rather than torch `Dataset`s. Thank you for the help! I didn't mean to offend by temporarily deselecting your answer, I was merely looking to open a discussion :)

Comment: A discussion is perfectly fine, I'd love to have one :) it's just that by deselecting the answer that actually offered the solution could cause people with that exact question to skip over it because it may or may not work. A discussion and an accepted answer aren't mutually exclusive. No offense received over here :)

Comment: If you want the outputs of the random split to be MapDataPipes, just wrap the outputs in `SequenceWrapper()`. I've updating the answer to include the code.